# How do I find all the documents in a Mongodb database that match a certain URI params with the Mongoose find() method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making an API, and although there are a number of tutorials that detail how to retrieve documents from a Mongodb database using the Mongoose findById() method, I can't seem to find a way to retrieve a number of documents based on other values.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var referenceRoute = router.route('/purchases/:reference')

referenceRoute.get(function(req, res) {
    Model.find(req.params.reference, function(err, purchases) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(purchases);
    });
});
```

The purpose of this is to allow users to retrieve the documents that contain those reference values through their URI params, such as www.example.com/api/purchases/674332457.

If it's of relevance I'm using Express, Node.js, Mongodb, Mongoose, and body-parser.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose model `find` function accepts `filter` parameter. You can create any query to select documents: `{ field1: value1, field2: value2... }`. Also, you can use the most of the mongodb operators, such as `$and, $or`, etc.

```
referenceRoute.get(function(req, res) {
    var filter = { url: req.params.reference };
    Model
      .find(filter)
      .then(purchases => res.send(purchases))
      .catch(err => res.send(err));
});
```

Btw, Mongoose supports promises, so much better use them, instead of callbacks. Besides of this your current code has bug, in the case of error you send response twice, it's fixed in my example.

Comment: Thanks @alexmac, you're a gentleman and a scholar. Your solution worked well (though I had to change `url` to `reference`), though I managed to find a question that discussed the security of using queries in URLs and that solution seemed to work a treat (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917400/how-dangerous-is-a-mongo-query-which-is-fed-directly-from-a-url-query-string). I'm going to include that as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I found that seemed to work really well for using URL query strings as Mongodb queries. So that if someone queries, say, www.example.com/api/purchases/query?reference=12345 then they will get all of the documents in a collection that match that reference value.

```
var referenceRoute = router.route('/purchases/query')

referenceRoute.get(function (req, res) {
  Model.find(req.query, function (err, donations) {
        res.send(donations);
    });
});
```

It'd probably be better to call it something like `var queryRoute = router.route('/purchases/query')` because it works for different queries (though I can't seem to get it to work on multiple queries yet).

The original answer was found here ([How dangerous is a mongo query which is fed directly from a URL query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917400/how-dangerous-is-a-mongo-query-which-is-fed-directly-from-a-url-query-string)).