# Parse-Server query fed directly from URL query string

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I'd like to know if this is even possible.  And if it is possible, what the security ramifications would be.

I want to use Javascript to build a dynamic URL to query a Parse-Server database.

It appears that it might be possible based on an earlier Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917400/how-dangerous-is-a-mongo-query-which-is-fed-directly-from-a-url-query-string) and a Node.js doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)

Here's how I envision it working....

So, a user would be sent (via email/Twitter/etc) a link which was created by above method.  Once the user clicked on that URL link, the following would happen automatically:

Step #1:  User's system would automatically submit a parse-server query.

Step #2:  On success, the user's browser would download a web page which displayed the query results.

Answer (score 0):

step one create the pointer value ie the query pseudo-semantic

step 2 insert the pointer value to a text-type field in parse cls=clazz

step 2b mailgun a msg containing a link like :

**express.domain.com/#!clazz/:yALNMbHWoy** - where 'yA...oy' is oid of pointer row in parse/clazz table

Note that the link is an abstraction only. Its a uri first to express/route  && function that will simply get a row from parse.clazz. That row contains the semantic for making a parse query to get back the full DB compliment to pass along to the node template setting up the html ...

in your node/router  GET/clazz/:oid   will lookup that Parse row in parse/clazz, using the pointer/text value to format a 2nd, Parse query. The query response from the 2nd  parse.qry is your real meat ... This response can be used by the express template formatting the html response to orig request on "express.domain.com".

where u ask "download web page"  .. that is simply node's RESPONSE to a GET on a route like "GET/clazz".

Comment: OK!  So, I'll know the Parse ObjectId, and I'll want in inject it into the URL.  sounds doable.  Thanks.  Will work on understanding.  thanks.